# Applying a theme/style to all html/react tags with a selector within a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'll try to give a minimal example for what I'm trying to achieve, I am using [Material UI Styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api) to style my components, I wanted to style all the `<Link>` tags in my component, so for example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    menuLink: theme.styles.menuLinkStyle,
}));

function DrawerContents() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    // noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={classes.toolbar}>
                <Link to='/' className={classes.menuLink}> {/*<==== This*/}
                    Hello
                </Link>
            </div>
            <Divider/>
            <List>
                <Link to={'/users'} className={classes.menuLink}> {/*<==== This*/}
                    World
                </Link>
            </List>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DrawerContents;
```

As you can see, I need to manually give the `className={classes.menuLink}` to each and every `<Link>` tag, I was wondering if there is a possibility to assign the `classes.menuLink` to every `<Link>` tag by default, something like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    Link: theme.styles.menuLinkStyle,
}));
```

Without the need to write `className={classes.menuLink}` for each `<Link>` tag in my component.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: I'm not sure if globals work on non-MUI components like Link from react-router, but this looks like what you want to do; maybe try with Link and add in your styles and see if it works. https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/

Comment: I haven't tried it with non-MUI components, but this will change it globally, I want to implement the styling for the component alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would handle this is to create a new component that takes care of the styling:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    menuLink: theme.styles.menuLinkStyle,
}));

function MenuLink(props) {
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    return <Link {...props} className={classes.menuLink}/>;
}
```

Then import this component and use it instead of `Link`.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you